# Should you define a null/unknown value for Java enums?

Tags: java, enums, null

When you define an enum for something that can be "undefined" in your interfaces, should you

- define a separate enum value for that, or
- just use enumValue = null for those situations?

For example,

serviceX.setPrice(Price priceEnum)

```
enum Price {
 CHEAP, EXPENSIVE, VERRRY_EXPENSIVE, UNKNOWN
}
```

and priceEnum.UNKNOWN when needed

or

```
enum Price {
 CHEAP, EXPENSIVE, VERRRY_EXPENSIVE
}
```

and priceEnum = null when needed?

Having a little debate on this. Some points that come to mind:

- using Price.UNKNOWN saves some "if (price == null)" code. You can handle Price x's all values in a single switch-case
- Depending on view technology, it may be easier to localize Price.UNKNOWN
- using Price.UNKNOWN kind of causes "magic number" problem in the code, IMO. Here we have Price.UNKNOWN, elsewhere maybe Color.UNDEFINED, Height.NULLVALUE, etc
- using priceValue = null is more uniform with how other data types are handled in Java. We have Integer i = null, DomainObject x = null, String s = null for unknown values as well, don't we?
- Price.UNKNOWN forces you to decide whether null value is allowed univerally for all use cases. We may have method Price getPrice() which may return Price.UNKNOWN and setPrice(Price p) which is not allowed to accept Price.UNKNOWN. Since Price.UNKNOWN is always included in the enum's values, those interfaces look a little unclean. I know priceValue = null has the same problem (you cannot define in the interface whether null is accepted or not) but it feels a little cleaner and a little less misleading(?)

Comment: you can't use `null` in a switch and that's a major downside.

Comment: Good points by all. Lessening the burden of null-handling, and ability to be more specific on what "null value" means are good points pro Price.UNKNOWN. Also, good point on "null object pattern", it makes Price.UNKNOWN feel like more "valid" and commonly accepted solution. But, no one feels the same way about Price.UNKNOWN negative aspects? I feel having Price.UNKNOWN pollutes the enum's value set. Say in showAllPrices(), I cannot just enumerate all enum values anymore, I have to add if (!Price.UNKNOWN), which feels a little dirty and "magic-numbery".

Comment: *@user449236*: If you don't like checking for this special value, add a `display` flag to each enum and check for it instead. Cleaner and more flexible.

Comment: see, it's simple, Take C for example, you can't have a null for enum (as they are actually real int). In my understanding having a non-declared value (i.e. null) is a bad practice and usually an error. Undeclared values do not tell what the purpose is, i.e. it should be skipped, it has been a result of an error (hence and exception should [have] be thrown)

Comment: A (very late) input on this.  In my experience - if you are writing code that is to be reused, extended or forms part of an API - you will have to account for client code passing or setting null anyway to be robust.  And that generally mitigates against any benefits from a special Foo.NIL value.  It also makes it harder to write type-agnostic methods / utils since they will not (in general) be aware that one of the values is 'special'.

Answer (score 29):

This is actually an example of applying [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). IMHO it is always better to have a dummy object rather than null. For instance you can add dummy methods to null-object rather than scattering your code with null-checks all over the place. Very convenient.

Also the name of the `enum` gives you some additional semantics: is the price *unknown*, *undefined*, not *trustworthy*, not yet *known*? And what does it mean if the price is *null*?

UPDATE: As *Aaron Digulla* points out, Null Object pattern requires memory. But this isn't actually the case most of the time. In the traditional implementation you typically have a singleton for Null object used everywhere as there is no need for separate instances. It gets even better with enums because you get singleton semantics for free.

Another point is that `null` reference and reference to some object occupy the same amount of memory (say 4 bytes on 32-bit machine). It is the object being referenced that occupies some extra memory. But if this is a singleton, there is practically no memory overhead here.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the pattern. One point to notice: The main reason why people don't use the pattern is because it needs memory (`null` pointers don't need memory). But they forget that this makes the code more complex (-> more time spent to develop and debug it), complexity is strongly related to number of bugs and more code lines means the *code* needs more memory, so that decision is often a loss on *all* frontiers.

Comment: Good point, I actually edited my question to address your comment.

Comment: `The main reason why people don't use the pattern is because it needs memory (null pointers don't need memory)` main reason is performance as null checks are easily eliminated by the JIT, null checks are hardware assisted and so on.

Answer (score 13):

I'd say go with `Price.UNKNOWN` if that's a valid value for a price.

I agree with the drawbacks of dealing with null references that you mention, and I think they motivate the decision enough.

New languages, take Scala for example (and some older ones, Haskell) strain away from null references all together and uses option / maybe monads instead... for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how are you going to use this enum. If you use it in switch/case statements it does not matter. 
If you create method(s) into the enum you actually must define UNKNOWN.

For example you can define abstract method 
`public abstract Icon icon();`

into your enum and then implement this method for each member of Price. Probably you will want to display question mark for unknown price. In this case just implement method `icon()` that creates appropriate icon.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Enum-Switch-Null-Trap](http://www.riedquat.de/blog/2011-03-04-02).
So it seems that just like with any property that is an object,
if it doesn't exist then it is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Color or Height would be used in the program logic. Them cannot handle with an undefined color.
A Price is userdata and may be unknown.
The color may be userdata else, but to be used as color in the code, they must be defined.

So Price may be UNKNOWN (instead of null), Color not (null may indicate error).